# c++ enable, disable class member functions?

Tags: c++11, gcc4.8

Is it possible to enable, disable class member functions?

Situation:
I have a class with 2 types. Each Type has a own constructor. One Type need a function which must not have the other Type.

Example:

```
class A {
    enum struct TypeEnum : int {
        TYPE_1 = 1,
        TYPE_2 = 2
    };
    const TypeEnum type;

    int x;


    A(void) : type(TypeEnum::TYPE_1) { }
    A(int _x) : type(TypeEnum::TYPE_2) { 
        x = _x;
    }


    // function only for Type 2
    void A::operator += (const int& n) {
        x = x + n;
    }
};

int main() {
    A test1 = new A();
    A test2 = new A(1);

    test1 += 5;  // compiler error should be here
    test2 += 5;  // OK

    return 0;
}
```

Is where something possible like this:

```
class A {
    enum struct TypeEnum : int {
        TYPE_1 = 1,
        TYPE_2 = 2
    };
    const TypeEnum type;

    int x;


    A(void) : type(TypeEnum::TYPE_1) { }
    A(int _x) : type(TypeEnum::TYPE_2) { 
        x = _x;
    }


    // Is somethig like this realy impossible
    void A::operator += (const int& n) -> enable_if(type == TypeEnum::Type2) { // if not compile error
        x = x + n;
    }
};
```

Comment: Easiest would be to add an assert and wait for the runtime error. Otherwise, this kind of thing is more often done with derivation.

Comment: It would be easy to use different classes and polymorphism but I want to use it with the same name (in this example A) and two classes with the same name are not possible. Even they have different constructors.

Comment: This is already not valid C++. Did you mean to use `new` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use specialization:

```
enum struct TypeEnum : int {
    TYPE_1 = 1,
    TYPE_2 = 2
};

template<TypeEnum Type>
class A;

template<>
class A<TypeEnum::TYPE_1>
{
public:
    A(void) { }
};

template<>
class A<TypeEnum::TYPE_2>
{
public:
    A(int _x) { 
        x = _x;
    }
    int x;
    void operator += (const int& n) {
        x = x + n;
    }
};

int main() {
    A<TypeEnum::TYPE_1> test1;
    A<TypeEnum::TYPE_2> test2{1};

    test1 += 5;  // compiler error should be here
    test2 += 5;  // OK

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. I will try it. Is there also a way to "split" the classes by there constructors not by the template?

Comment: For my task is this the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Maybe following may help:

```
class A {
public:
    explicit A(TypeEnum type) : type(type) {}
    virtual ~A() {}
protected:
    enum struct TypeEnum : int {
        TYPE_1 = 1,
        TYPE_2 = 2
    };
    const TypeEnum type;
};

class B : public A{
public:
    B() : A(TYPE_1) {}
};

class C : public A{
public:
    explicit C(int x) : A(TYPE_2), x(x) {}
    C& operator += (int n) { x = x + n; }
private:
    int x;
};
```

inheritance is here to reflect your case with a common type. it is not required else.

A thing you can do anyway:

```
B make_A() { return B{}; }
C make_A(int x) { return C{x}; }

int main() {
    auto test1 = make_A();  // B
    auto test2 = make_A(1); // C

    test1 += 5;  // compiler error should be here
    test2 += 5;  // OK

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really nice but not the solution way for my task.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that you didn't get compilation error here:

```
// function only for Type 2
void A::operator += (const int& n) {
    x = x + n;
}
```

I thought you wanted something like:

```
// function only for Type 2
A& operator += (int n) {
    x = x + n;
    return *this;
}
```

Answering on your question - C++ doesn't work like this. Nevertheless you can implement something similar with templates but I suggest not to do it unless it's just a test program.

Comment: That's right I want to return x here. It is a mistake. I tried to get my problem to the minimum and not to post 1000 rows of code.

Comment: @Heinrich consider `template<int Type> class A;` and then you need to write two specialisations for 1 and 2. `template<> class A<1> { ...implementation with operator+=... };` and `template<> class A<2> { ...implementation without operator+= };`. As result A<1> will have += and A<2> will be without it.

Comment: There's nothing illegal about returning `void`, so it would be strange if he did get a compilation error.

Comment: @BenVoigt it's not about void - gcc prints the following error: `main.cpp:1:20: error: extra qualification on member 'operator+='`

Comment: Ah yes, that's the syntax to use outside the class and he put it inside.