# C++ - enable usage of member functions under condition that member class was intialize

Tags: c++, oop, runtime-error, compile-time

Assume that I have a class that doesn't hold any members and does calculations:

```
class Helper{
public: 
    bool f1(TypeA a, TypeB b, Result& res){
        // Some calculation requires TypeA, and TypeB and are assigned to the result
        return true;
    }
    
    bool f2(TypeC c, Result& res){
        // Some calculation requires TypeC and assign to the result
        return true;
    }
    
    bool f3(TypeA a, TypeC c, Result& res){
        // Some calculation requires TypeC and assign to the result
        return true;
    }
    
    bool f4(Result& res){
        // Some calculation that doesn't require anything and is assigned to the result
        return true;
    }
```

};

Where TypeA, TypeB, and TypeC are some types.

I want to make use of the helper class only if I have those types, some functions may not require any member class, some require only TypeC, some require two types, etc.,so I have the following class:

```
class Item{

public: 

// Constructors, may or may not initialize some values
Item(){} 
Item(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeC c):a_(a),b_(b),c_(c){}
Item(TypeB b, TypeC c):b_(b),c_(c){}


// usage of member functions 
bool f1(Result& res){
    if (a_.has_value() && b_.has_value())
    {
        return h.f1(a_.value(),b_.value(),res);
    } 
    // runtime error 
    throw std::logic_error("some msg");
}

bool f2(Result& res){
    // Allow only if c was initiated
    if (c_.has_value())
    {
        return h.f2(c_.value(), res);
    } 
    // runtime error 
    throw std::logic_error("some msg");
}

bool f4(Result& res){
        // Doesn't require any member class
        return h.f4(res);
}

private:

std::optional<TypeA> a_;
std::optional<TypeB> b_;
std::optional<TypeC> c_;
Helper h;
```

};

So users can expect to have Helper functionality only if they use it correctly and initiate the required members. But this is a runtime error and not a compile-time error. So I thought maybe I could allow compilation only if the conditions are met.

I was looking into this thread:
[c++ enable, disable class member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648237/c-enable-disable-class-member-functions)

But this can cause code duplications (Because I will need to copy each function to those classes), and not maintainable since for each added function I  will need to ask myself "Which of the classes can use this function?". So maybe there is a better solution? I would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: `Helper` looks like it should be a `namespace` instead of a `class`.

Comment: It would be true if I had not used overriding and same name functions (I didn't add it here because it would bloat the question)

Comment: So, they are `virtual` functions? Who inherits from the class? It seems some pieces of the puzzle are missing

Comment: Sorry, I meant overloading, NOT overriding. 

Helper is only a functionality that acts as a calculator.

Comment: Ok, but you can do overloading in a `namespace` too.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible without splitting `Item` into multiple types.  Consider `Item i{}; if (rand() % 2 == 0) i = Item{a, b, c}; f1(res);`.  Should that result in an error?  There's no way to know until runtime when `rand()` executes, which is too late for a compile-time error.

Comment: That's an excellent point, but I could just disable the assign operator, I wouldn't care if the user would create another object for the purpose of another calculation, it is a tradeoff, and there is no solution that is a saint.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not making `Item` the same type when initialized with `TypeA` and `TypeB` as when initialized with all three - or only `TypeC`. These `Item`s don't share a common interface and do not carry the same data. I'd make `Item` a class template.

Here I use a `std::tuple` as a private base class to store the values for the supplied types.

Example:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// Helper trait to check if a type is any of the supplied types
template <class T, class... Ts>
inline constexpr bool is_any_of_v = std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>;

template <class... Ts>
class Item : private std::tuple<Ts...> {
public:
    using std::tuple<Ts...>::tuple;
    using std::tuple<Ts...>::operator=;

    template<class A = TypeA, class B = TypeB> 
    std::enable_if_t<is_any_of_v<A, Ts...> && is_any_of_v<B, Ts...>, bool>
    f1(Result& res) {
        return Helper::f1(std::get<TypeA>(*this), std::get<TypeB>(*this), res);
    }

    template<class C = TypeC>
    std::enable_if_t<is_any_of_v<C, Ts...>, bool>
    f2(Result& res) {
        return Helper::f2(std::get<TypeC>(*this), res);
    }

    bool f4(Result& res) {
        // Doesn't require any member class
        return Helper::f4(res);
    }
};
template <class... Ts>
Item(Ts...) -> Item<std::remove_cvref_t<Ts>...>;
```

Note: I've here placed your `Helper` functions in a `namespace`.

It could then be used like so:

```cpp
int main() {
    TypeA a;
    TypeB b;
    Result r;
    Item item(a, b);
    item.f1(r);
    // item.f2(r); // compilation error, has no TypeC so f2() doesn't exist
}
```

`item` in the above example with be of type `Item<TypeA, TypeB>` which will not have any relation with an `Item<TypeC>` or `Item<TypeB, TypeA>` etc. Each unique combination of types you supply to `Item` will produce a unique type.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e8TsWhz1M)

With C++20, you could replace the `std::enable_if_t`s with `requires` clauses:
[Demo kindly provided by Miles Budnek](https://godbolt.org/z/GKEnjjT9n)

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that those member function templates could be turned into `requires` clauses with C++20: https://godbolt.org/z/eKoaWd7b4

Comment: @MilesBudnek Indeed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra template parameter T with a default of the type you want to check for (TypeA or TypeC) Use std::enable_if along with std::is_same to enable the function only if T matches the desired type Now f1 is only enabled if TypeA is present, f2 only if TypeC is present, etc.

```
    #include <type_traits>
#include <optional>

class Helper {
  // Same as before 
};

class Item {
public:

  template <typename T = TypeA, 
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, TypeA>>>
  bool f1(TypeA a, TypeB b, Result& res) {
    return h.f1(a, b, res); 
  }

  template <typename T = TypeC,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, TypeC>>>  
  bool f2(TypeC c, Result& res) {
    return h.f2(c, res);
  }

  bool f4(Result& res) {
    return h.f4(res);
  }

private:
  std::optional<TypeA> a_;
  std::optional<TypeB> b_;
  std::optional<TypeC> c_;
  
  Helper h;
};
```

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake in my functions signiture, so I have only f1,f2,f3,f4 but it will use the helper and only accepts argument Result (becuase it does have what he need in his member functions).